# Anybody knows the technology approach behind livelook.com's concept?

Tags: ajax, screen

Livelook.com "shares" screens without requiring shared parties to download nor install anything. These are my guesses on how it works:

- Proxy server keeping track of shared parties who both are browsing the same website (thus not really screen sharing)
- Interaction is being "recorded" by host side javascript and then serialized over to the client's javascript (ajax) who will then have to de-serialize the actions from the host and mimic the behaviour.

Anyone else has a take on this?

Comment: I'm wondering the same thing. I noticed that the company used to sell videoconferencing software so that's a strong suggestion of the kind of technology used. But how does it avoid downloading some kind of a plugin or executable?

Comment: As I understand it, their system allows screen sharing beyond simply the contents of a webpage.  I have no clue how they can screen capture and allow for mouse control/tracking without a download.  I assume that it is flash-based...but have not yet tried it out (i am too cheap to pay the $10/use just to see it in action...and currently no free demo, just an animated video).  Would be great to know how they did it (or even better if there is an open-source equivalent to play with somewhere).

Comment: It could perhaps be Native Client. I'm not really sure if that allows for that level of access however.

Answer (score 1):

I did some research on this, and I'm pretty sure it uses Java since that is one of the requirements.

"To use LiveLOOK's screen sharing and co browsing products you will need a browser and java. Java is typically pre-installed on all computers. If your computer d..."

http://www.livelook.com/faq.asp

Here is perhaps how they get access to the screen:

http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/code/216988/java-code-to-capture-your-screen-as-image

But I'm a C++ man so, I wouldn't know if there's a better way to do things like that in Java.